# HTML only text next to an image (same hight)

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm new to wordpress and the shortcode stuff. I tried to set a text (numbers) next to images.

This is the way i put the image on the website

`<div align="right"><p><img src="/metin2%20content/icons/Schriftrolle_des_Drachen.png"></p></div>`

that looked good so far [WEBSITE](http://xciid.net/metin2-mondlicht-schatztruhe-event/)

My problem now is to set a number, for example 45 next to the small images next to the progress bars on the left site. I've tried with inline and already found something that basically looked like a solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/yLH25/

But it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put the number before the img?

45http://xciid.net/metin2%20content/icons/Schriftrolle_des_Drachen.png

```
<div align="right"><p>45<img src="http://xciid.net/metin2%20content/icons/Schriftrolle_des_Drachen.png"></p></div>
```

Comment: Its not as easy as this :/

I already tryed `<div align="right"><p> <font size="5">45 </font><img src="/metin2%20content/icons/Schriftrolle_des_Drachen.png"></p></div>`

The problem is, that the font isnt realy on the same "hight" as the icon so it looks a bit weird.

Answer (score 0):

this should do it:

## Updated:

This is the current structure:

```
<div class="row>
    <div class="md-column col-md-3">
    <div class="md-column col-md-9">
</div>
```

Take the number out of the second child div, and create another, like so:

```
<div class="row>
    <div class="md-column col-md-3">
    <div class="md-column col-md-1">
    <div class="md-column col-md-7">
</div>
```

if you keep the align="right" on the picture, it should hug the right side, right next to the number. Play with the col-md-7, i suspect your css is going to throw it to the next line.

Comment: [link](http://xciid.net/metin2-mondlicht-schatztruhe-event/) - doesnt seems like. the `align="right" is necesarry to put the icon next to the progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

Well, thanks for the suggestions!

This nearly fixed it: `<div align="right" style="float: right;"><p style="font-size:1.9em; margin-top:18px;">45 <img src="http://www.metin2wiki.eu/images/4/47/Schriftrolle_des_Drachen.png"></p></div>`

the font is still like 2px to high or something like that but it looks "ok" right now. Thanks!